# ImportError: No module named py3compat

Tags: paramiko

ubuntu 14.04
I am using Python 2.7.6
I have already installed paramiko moudle

for example:

~/paramiko/demos$ python demo.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 31, in 
from paramiko.py3compat import input
ImportError: No module named py3compat

so I open the demo.py

vim demo.py +31

line31: from paramiko.py3compat import input

Answer (score 0):

You need install paramiko before import it. Try

`pip install paramiko`