# ImportError: No module named elftools.common.py3compat

Tags: python

Trying to execute a python script, I receive this error message:

```
$ Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./abc.py", line 19, in <module>
import elftools.common.py3compat
ImportError: No module named elftools.common.py3compat
```

I tried to resolve the issue as follows (along the lines of [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192016/importerror-no-module-named-py3compat)):

```
pip install paramiko
```

It seems to install without any problems:

```
$ pip show paramiko
Name: paramiko
Version: 2.2.1
Summary: SSH2 protocol library
Home-page: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/
Author: Jeff Forcier
Author-email: jeff@bitprophet.org
License: LGPL
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: pynacl, pyasn1, bcrypt, cryptography
```

However, it does not resolve the initial dependency problem. Executing the script again results in the same error message that py3compat module cannot be found.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/xyz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Did the script come with a file with a name similar to `requirements.txt`? If so do `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If it didn't come with a requirements file, try `pip install pyelftools`.

Comment: No, the scripts are custom implementations.

Comment: Did you try `pip install pyelftools`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I resolved the issue. I installed paramiko using sudo. However, I had to pass the -H switch to sudo, such that the installation was valid for the normal user:

```
sudo -H pip install paramiko
```